# Mac messages - file - save as pdf is greyed out

Tags: macos, messages

I have to save entire message conversations for legal and compliance purposes in my business, but in the Messages app of macOS Ventura 13.2.1, the first four options under the File menu as well as the "Quick Look" are suddenly greyed out. I also cannot print to pdf in the app because it crashes.

How do I get them back?

Comment: Can you pls clarify what exactly is greyed out? On the other hand, the messages app crashes on my Mac as well when the conversation I am trying to print has a message in it with a picture. I am able to print a conversation (also to PDF) only when it has no messages with a picture.

Comment: What OS version are you on? Printing to PDF from Messages works for me on Ventura. Can you print to PDF in other applications? Do you have any printer queues set up?

Comment: Ventura 13.2.1. In messages-file- the 1st 4 options are greyed as well as "quick look"

Comment: Those top four options under the File menu from Duplicate to Export As in addition to Quick Look are also greyed out in my Messages app (v14.0) under macOS Ventura 13.2.1. I can not have any of them activated no matter what I do either. No "Save As PDF" option under the File menu though.

Comment: You indicate in your post that certain items under the File menu were suddenly greyed out. Have they been available / working previously? I got to work Quick Look by the way. It gets activated when you select a picture or file in a conversation. When you then select Quick Look, it shows the picture as enlarged or the contents of the file.